# Converting python to exe gives an exe with black screen

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe

I have made a python app in one python file with the following import statements:

```
import numpy as np
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import cv2 
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import sys
import os
import pydicom as dicom
from io import BytesIO
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pydicom.pixel_data_handlers import convert_color_space
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
```

When I run my app (in spyder), it gives simply a window telling the user to select a folder:
[image]

When the user chooses a folder and click ok, the app starts to open other window with buttons to click on etc. I have tested in spyder many times that my code does not contain error and in particular will not crush. My goal is to convert this one single python file into an exe such that the user can just double click on exe (without python environment) such that the code starts to run and they should see the window telling them to select folders immediately after double click.

I use pyinstaller for the task (with command `pyinstaller --onefile main.py`, where `main.py` is the my file. The process is slow (and produces a lot of text) but there does not seem to have errors. When I click on the final exe file, I get two empty windows:

[image]

What can there possibly go wrong? Is there any workaround to this? That is, is there anything other than pyinstaller to help me with the task?

Comment: Your application uses a large number of packages that are tricky when trying to combine them into an EXE file.  There is going to be some research needed by you on each one of them like OpenCV, PIL, scipy, etc, and how they behave when used with PyInstaller.  It's a real challenge to turn a lot of packages into an EXE file.

Comment: Try to run it in console mode to check if any exception or message.